# Ionic v1 modal destroyed before leave animation is complete

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When using the default slide-in-up animation for an Ionic (v1) modal, the modal leave animation looks perfect. But when substituting a different animation ( I am using slide-in-right) the modal is destroyed (i.e. removed from the DOM) before the leave animation is done. Here's my code:

JS:

```
//create the modal
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/my-modal.html', function(modal) {
  $scope.myModal = modal;
  }, {
   scope: $scope,
   animation: 'slide-in-right'
});

//show the modal
$scope.myModal.show()

//hide the modal
$scope.myModal.hide();
```

and the CSS (the timings are long just for debugging purposes):

```
.slide-in-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%); }

.slide-in-right.ng-enter, .slide-in-right > .ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 1) 2000ms;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.7, 0.1, 1) 2000ms; }

.slide-in-right.ng-enter-active, .slide-in-right > .ng-enter-active {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0); }

.slide-in-right.ng-leave, .slide-in-right > .ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 2800ms;
  transition: all linear 2800ms; }
```

This causes a noticeable UX hiccup, since the modal is only half way through the leave animation before it just disappears. You can see this here:

http://codepen.io/frey1esm/pen/QvOQjO

The leave timing in this codepen is 2500ms so that's how long the modal should be visible as it slides out to the left. But it gets removed almost instantly. IS there a way to delay the removal of the modal from the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know if there a good ionic answer to that 
anyway my workaround will be custom class conditions 
http://codepen.io/islam4hak/pen/JNOepN
on the ion modal use a condition class name

```
 <ion-modal-view ng-class="GoingAway==1 ? 'slide-in-left ng-leave' : ' '">
```

and for the controller

```
  $scope.GoingAway = 0;
  $scope.CustomHide = function(e){
    $scope.GoingAway = 1;
    setTimeout(function(){
          $scope.modal.hide();
         $scope.GoingAway = 0;
    },2600)

  }
```

Hope that this work for you

Comment: Very simple solution. Another option to speed up the leave timing to 200ms which allows the modal to be gone before being removed, but this is more flexible.

Comment: i did $scope.GoingAway = 0; after modal.hide() to prevent the 1 time working issue sill you needs to create a conditional class for the re-entering